# Let $A$ be $m\times n$ and $B$ be $n\times m$ matrices with $AB=I_m$, then $A$ and $B$ have the same rank.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be $m\times n$ and $B$ be $n\times m$ matrices, with $AB=I_m$. I want to show $A,B$ have same rank.

---

First I know since $AB=I_m$, $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=m$ and $\operatorname{nullity}(AB)=0$ and hence each nullity of $A,B$ are $0$ indicates $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n, \operatorname{rank}(B)=m$. Since $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq \min\{m,n\}$, and the same thing holds for $B$, $m$ should be $n$ and hence $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(B)$.

Is my trial correct? Is there any other ways to show this?

---

Sorry for the confusion; I notice your points.   $\operatorname{nullity}(AB) \geq \operatorname{nullity}(B)$ is true for general matrix $A,B$ but
$\operatorname{nullity}(AB) \geq \operatorname{nullity}(A)$ holds for square matrix $A,B$. Before working on the formula directly, I should check the correct condition.  Thanks for many comments!

Comment: Do you really believe that the nullity of $A$ has to be $0$? Isn't $n-m>0$ in general?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, I know $\operatorname{nullity}(AB) \geq \max\{ \operatorname{nullity}(A), \operatorname{nullity}(B)\}$, and since nullity of $AB$ is zero I conclude nullity of A,B are zero.

Comment: Well, you’d better think more critically here. Is what you “know” correct? What’s the proof?

Comment: Think more critically about the other claims. How can the rank of $A$ be $n$?

Comment: Note that $AB = I_m$ is only possible for $m \le n$.

Comment: It's not "just square matrices". What happens is that in general $\mathrm{nullity}(B)\leq\mathrm{nullity}(AB)$, and $\mathrm{rank}(AB)\leq\mathrm{rank}(A)$. If $A$ is $n\times m$ and $B$ is $m\times p$, then $AB$ is $n\times p$, so $\mathrm{rank}(AB)=p-\mathrm{nullity(AB)}$, and $\mathrm{rank}(A)=m-\mathrm{nullity}(A)$.  So $\mathrm{nullity}(AB)-\mathrm{nullity}(A)\geq p-m$. If $p\geq m$, then you get $\mathrm{nullity}(A)\leq\mathrm{nullity}(AB)$. It happens in particular if $p=m$, but not only in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The claim that $\mathrm{nullity}(AB)\geq \max\{\mathrm{nullity}(A),\mathrm{nullity}(B)\}$ is incorrect.

It is true that $\mathrm{nullity}(AB)\geq\mathrm{nullity}(B)$, since the nullspace of $B$ is contained in the nullspace of $AB$. But you have no warrant to claim that the nullity of $AB$ is at least as large as the nullity of $A$.

Consider the case where $B=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right)$ is $2\times 1$ with nullity $0$, and $A=(1\quad 0)$ is $1\times 2$ with nullity $1$. Then $AB=(1)$ has nullity $0$, so $\mathrm{nullity}(A)\gt\mathrm{nullity}(AB)$. I don't know where you got the inequality you claim: it's not true.

To (mis)quote Mark Twain: It's not what you don't know that kills you, it's what you "know" that just ain't so.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not correct: Take $A:\mathbb R^2\mapsto R^3$ as $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $AB = I_2$ but $n\neq m$.

Rather consider: If $AB=I_m$ then clearly $m\leq n$ (as the rank of $AB$ is at most the rank of $B$, which is at most $n$ (since the image of $B$ is a subspace of $K^n$).

Also this shows that $A,B$ (which have at most rank $m$) must have rank $m$, else $AB$ will also have strictly smaller rank (as the image of $AB$ is a subspace of the image of $A$, and the dimension of the image of $AB$ is at most the dimension of the image of $B$).

Comment: $A$ and $B$ have rank $2$ in your eaxmple.

Comment: "That is not correct" presumably refers to the claim that the nullity of $A$ must be zero, since in your example the nullity is $1$...

Comment: @PaulFrost Sorry, that was about the claim that $n=m$, not about the actual statement, which is correct.